# Cannot resolve symbol 'router-outlet'

Tags: angular

Angular 13

Добавил в проект маршрутизацию.
app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {HomePageComponent} from "./home-page/home-page.component";

const appRoutes: Routes =[
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

добавил AppRoutingModule  в файл app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {ModalModule} from "ngb-modal";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page/home-page.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomePageComponent
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

но если пытаюсь добавить в файл app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

IDEA выдает ошибку

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'router-outlet'
```

Причем открываю другой проект с маршрутизацией в этой же IDE, там такой ошибки нет.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4409379867154

Answer (score 2):

Это баг IDE от JetBrains на 13 версии Angular.

На PhpStorm 2021.3.1 баг не наблюдается.
Нужно просто обновиться до последней версии.

Comment: Подтверждаю, обновление решает проблему. Спасибо!